# creating a .deb from archlinux tar.xz

Tags: deb, packaging, nemo

I am trying to install the latest commit (4.0.3) of Nemo file manager on Ubuntu 18.04. It finally fixes the bug where searches do not include hidden folders. Since there is no `configure` file in the commit, I am unable to make the build. Arch Linux has a compiled version of nemo 4.0.3 but I'm lost on how to install it or create a Debian package. Is anyone able to look at it and help me? Thanks. [Nemo 4.03 from Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/nemo/download/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source-based method will fail (see below), but you can install compiled package from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon?field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/cinnamon
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

and enjoy:

[image: Nemo 4 on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS]

---

According to [PKGBUILD](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/nemo) you need to use `meson`.

So you should download Ubuntu-specific build-dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nemo
```

then download the Nemo source from official repository:

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo.git
cd nemo
git checkout 4.0.3
```

then install `meson` and compile the package:

```
sudo apt-get install meson
mkdir build
cd build
meson
```

but it will not compile because of old version of `xapp` library:

> Native dependency xapp found: NO found '1.0.4' but need: '>=1.4.0'
>
> meson.build:84:0: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'xapp' ['>=1.4.0'] found '1.0.4'.

So it seems that you can't install it on 18.04 LTS...